# How to prove that there does not exist a natural number '$n$' whose product of digits is $n^3-25n^2+151n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

How to prove that there does not exist a natural number '$n$' whose product of digits is $n^3-25n^2+151n$. I don't know where to start.

**NOTE**: I do not want the answer a hint should do it.

Any help appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Is there any fact that know when $n$ is compared with the product of its digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really want there to be a clever reason... but if you just want to know that it's true, observe that the product of the digits is less than $9 ^{ \log_{10}(n)}$ which is sub-linear, while your function grows like $n^3$, so there should be a small numer of cases to check before you can just say the two numbers are just too far apart.

Comment: yeah i also want a clever reason

Comment: I think i got it. Can you check the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think i got it

Let $n=10^{m-1}a_1+10^{m-2}a_2+ \cdots+a_m$, where $0\leq a_i \leq9$ , $i=2,3, \cdots m$ and $0<a_1 \leq 9$ , $a_i \in I$

Product of digits is $a_1a_2 \cdots a_m \leq9^{m-1}a_1\leq10^{m-1}a_1 \leq n$

So, $n^3-25n^2+151n<n \implies 10<n<15$.

The rest is easy.

Comment: The two $<$ should be $\leq$, e.g. the product of digits of $n=9$ equals $n$, so equality can be achieved.  (Also, what's $I$?)

Comment: @Rebecca Thank you for spotting that.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding an upper and lower bound for the product of digits, then compare that to the function.

Comment: I think i got it. Can you check the answer. thanks.

Comment: That's the same solution I had. If you add the lower bound of $0$ you will be left with only $n=10$ and $n=15$.